# How to get true raw data input from webcam? pref with python

Tags: python

Interested in getting the raw data that is streamed from a webcam..before it is transformed into binary -> pixels or whatever the sequence is.

From my understanding, libraries like opencv won't help with this.

Edit: kiss

Comment: An image is just a bunch of pixels with values of colors Red, Yellow, Blue. So what kind of raw data do you mean you want?

Comment: But these RGB values are a transformation of the data stream, not raw. I want the absolute raw information the sensor is capturing.

Comment: If you would like folk to help you, it's generally a good idea to make it easy for them... so maybe click [edit] and say which make/model of camera you are using and what operating system you are running. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I could be wrong, but I feel that attempting to specify for all of this information adds unnecessary complication to what should be a very simple answer.

I would expect what I am asking should only require a few lines of code, without requiring knowledge of OS or camera models.

edit: Kiss

Answer (score -1):

in order to see the image output from a webcam using python you need to convert it from raw image data (the pixels) into a image that can be displayed one way you can do it is by using matplotlib more info here https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/images.html
this will display the image but will not convert it into other image formats such as .png .jpeg ext. but the data you are getting is probably pixel data which is the rawest image data you will get

Comment: Doesn't answer my question, sorry.